# Looping Google Maps Markers with embedded ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, embedded-ruby

I'm new to rails and I'm wondering how exactly I could loop these markers. My JS variable "count" is not recognized and I need some help looping through my ruby array or need another solution.

```
 function initMap() {
          var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
          var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
              center: {lat: 44.540, lng: -78.546},
              zoom: 8
          });

          var total = <%= mapcount %>

          var javascriptcount = 0;

          var count = 0;

      <% arraylat = [] %> 
      <% arraylng = [] %> 

      <% mapposttotal.each do |q| %>
          <% arraylat << q.lat %> 
          <% arraylng << q.lng %> 
      <% end %>

          for (; javascriptcount <= total; javascriptcount++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: {lat: <%= arraylat[count] %>, lng: <%= arraylng[count] %>},
              map: map,
              title: 'Hello World!'
            });
            count = count + 1;
            console.log()
          }

        var Clicker = document.getElementById('PostIt');


        Clicker.addEventListener('click', function() {
            window.location='/newpost.html';}, false);

        }


    <% end %>
```

Comment: mixing up erb code and javascript is pretty bad. You'd better get the markers info through an ajax call(If they are stored in db) and populate them in `success` response

Answer (score 1):

As you are new to Rails, I can suggest this solution:

1.Add an action in `MarkersController`:

```
    def index
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json do 
          markers = Marker.all.map do |marker|
             {
               lat: marker.lat,
               lng: marker.lng
             }
          end
          render json: markers
        end
      end
    end
```

2.In `routes.rb`

```
get "/markers", to: "markers#index"
```

3.Javascript:

```
function initMap() {
  $.getJSON("/markers", function(data) {
    // All your js code to populate markers go in here. 
  })
}
```

That's basically how it should work. Just tailor the code to suit your need